# Retain double Quotes while Importing CSV File in pgAdmin -4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

When I tried to create an Import Job in pgAdmin 4, to copy the CSV File into the table, all double quotes are getting truncated. I am sure, something to do with Quote and Escape, not understanding, please help.

My CSV File looks like

[image]

After Import Job , the data Inserted is without double quotes in 'description' column.

Here are the Import Job from pgAdmin -
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

**Data in Excel File looks like**
{
"push": {
"title": "Recent  Detected",
"body": " were above target",
"expandedBody" : " more details about this pattern"
}
}

This is a sinle column Data. This is String Column. I want to Import as it it. But, if I import, the data that I am getting in the table is

{
push: {
title: Recent  Detected,
body: were above target,
expandedBody : more details about this pattern
}
}

```
| Id | description |
| ---| ------------|
| 1  | {
        "push": {
         "title": "Recent  Detected",
         "body": " were above target",
          "expandedBody" : " more details about this pattern"
        }
        }
-----------------------
```

Table Structure :

Create table abcd ( id integer, description character varying );

What I am trying to do is :

--Use Import function in pgAdmin 4 to populate the table with the Data from the above CSV File.

What is going on :

Data got inserted without the double quotes.

What is Expected :
Data should get Inserted with the quotes, as if the quotes are part of the string .

What is going wrong -

Import settings, something I am missing or not understanding.

Comment: Please show your file content in textual form - not as image.

Comment: If your file uses comma as delimiter your JSON should be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: If it's tab-delimited and without quotes, you use type TEXT instead of CSV

Comment: It is a CSV File, and a particular Column is having String values -- which contains double quotes. Yes, effectively, it contains json data for purpose. But, as the column itself is used by many other purpose, we need to put the string as it is. I am sure, there may be ways to ignore the double quotes and import as it is...

Comment: If your CSV uses comma delimiters, your JSON has to be enclosed in single quotes. Pease edit your question and include a line from your file as an example.

Comment: Ok, edited and given the example, data that I have, and data , I am getting after Import Job.

Comment: Json data need not to be in a single quote, think of it as a String column, The whole thing is a string. The data type is character varying. The content of the data may look like a json data.

Comment: It is irrelevant how your data looks in an excel cell. We need to see a line of the file you are trying to import.

Comment: I have edited the column value. Thats exactly the column value is. Please look into the last section of question.

Comment: There are various ways to export csv data from excel. Unless you show the exact data from your csv file, it is impossible to recommend import settings.

Comment: Ok, I could not find any option to attach an excel file. How you want me to show. I can create dummy data for you.

Comment: Ok, edited, please see the last section. If it helps..